# PHP: Variables in a Postgresql Query

Tags: php, postgresql

Let's say I have these two variables

```
$number = 1;
$word = "one";
```

and I want to use them in a pg_query.

This is what I've got:

```
$result = pg_query($con, 'UPDATE a SET z = ARRAY[{$number}] WHERE word = {pg_escape_literal($word)}');
```

But it doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use string interpolation, you have to use double quotes:

```
 $x = 3;
 "This works: $x"     // This works: 3
 'This does not: $x'; // This does not: $x
```

You also can't interpolate function calls into strings like you're attempting with `{pg_escape_literal($word)}`. You'll need to escape the variable before interpolating it into the string:

```
$word_esc = pg_escape_literal($word);
$result = pg_query(
  $con,
  "UPDATE a SET z = ARRAY[$number] WHERE word = $word_esc"
);
```

You could also use `sprintf`:

```
$result = pg_query(
  $con,
  sprintf(
    "update a set z=ARRAY[%d] where word = %s",
    $number,
    pg_escape_literal($word)
  )
);
```

But the best and safest is to use `pg_query_params` function, as you don't escape any parameter. And it is very easy to forget and expose your site to SQL-injection attacks.

```
$result = pg_query_params(
  'update a set z=ARRAY[$1] where word = $2',
  array($number,$word)
)
```

Comment: Using `pg_query_params` instead of escaping would be better.

Comment: I've edited meagar's answer - removed quotes in examples, as `pg_escape_literal` will quote variable, improved layout of examples and added `pg_query_params` example as it is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Use double instead of single quotes: Double quoted strings [expand variables into their values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).